# Web Page works when launched from Brackets or Visual Studio, breaks when launched from file

Tags: css, hyperlink

I hope there are not any questions like this out there, but I wouldn't even know what to search. A friend of mine created a web page for a class we are in together. When she launches it from Adobe Brackets or Visual Studio, it looks perfect. Yet, for some reasons, when she tries to open it through her files, it seems like all of the CSS and image links are broken. It's the same for Firefox and Chrome. But neither of us have any clue what this error could be. Anyone have any clue what this could be about?

Answer (score 0):

I think, and I will say that again, that the URL is different when you launch it from Visual Studio, than when you open it by double clicking the file. That being the case the webpage would be making inaccurate reference to the location of the files needed to load itself. Otherwise you are trying to open an ASP file or so, which needs to be parsed by the server not accessed directly.

Lastly, I think the URL that VisualStudio will give you look something like:

```
http://localhost/myindex.html
```

And the URL given to the browser when you launch the file from windows explorer looks like:

```
file:///c:/users/user/Documents/myindex.html
```

Comment: I'll give my friend this information and hope it helps. Thank you!